# AngularJS - Blur delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following:

```
<div class="staff">

    <input ng-model="user" 
            ng-focus="isFocused = true;"
            ng-blur="isFocused = false;/>

    <div class="matches" ng-if="isFocused">
        <div class="user" 
            ng-repeat="match in users | filter:user" 
            ng-bind="match"
            ng-click="user = match">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

With my directive on `.staff`. Basically, we have an input field. When you start typing, it shows the matches. I want to then click a match and that should update `ng-model='user'`.

Right now this doesn't work, because `ng-focus` quickly hides the `.matches` (that is, when you want to click on a `.match`, then you have blurred out of the input, so `isFocused` becomes `false`).

My solution currently is to rely on the directive `element.bind()` for the focus and blur, and basically delay the action.

So, in my current implementation, the `input` tag is simply `<input ng-model="user"/>` and my directive's `link` is

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs)
{
    element.bind('focus', function()
    {
        scope.isFocused = true;
    });

    element.bind('blur', function()
    {
        $timeout(function() 
        {
            scope.isFocused = false;
        }, 125);
    });
}
```

I really prefer the first option. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: So you're saying it disappears before the click event gets triggered?

Comment: @snowman4415, yes. The first approach sets `isFocused` to false as soon as `ng-blur` (which is right away) happens. So if I 'click' on a match, then I have blurred out, and so the blur is triggered and I cannot click

Comment: I personally think the directive is the most elegant solution, because every other way I can think of is even more hacky. By using the ng-if and ng-blur as you do, there's really no way around it. Also, is there a reason you're using ng-if instead of ng-hide here?

Comment: @snowman4415, yeah I guess you are right. And the reason is because I have a lot of these users per page, each with their own match. I use ng-if to remove it from the body to reduce the total number of doms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="staff">
    <input ng-model="user" 
            ng-focus="isFocused = true;"
            ng-blur="focusOut()"/>

    <div class="matches" ng-if="isFocused">
        <div class="user" 
            ng-repeat="match in users | filter:user" 
            ng-bind="match"
            ng-click="user = match">
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.focusOut = function(){
        $timeout(function(){
            scope.isFocused = false;
        }, 125);
    });
}
```